# Header file throwing errors in one project, but not in another

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm trying to integrate two projects, and to that end am including header files from one into the other. I'm using visual studio 2008 express.

The line

```
int E4407B_PPM(int &);
```

is throwing errors in the new project, but the original project compiles just fine.

The error I'm getting:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '&'
```

Any ideas?

Edit: I ended up removing the lines that took parameters in by reference, and just insured that all functions were declared before they were used in the actual source file. I guess it was a C++/C thing.

Comment: In cases like this, context is everything.  What are a few lines before this line?  If it's near the top of the header, check the previously included header to make sure it terminates properly (no unclosed delimiters, etc.).  Also, you might look at macro definitions.  The variable name is all-caps, and might have been used as a macro name.

Comment: Are you compiling the other project as C or as C++?

Comment: I'd guess the error isn't actually on that line, it's just being reported from there. Perhaps an error earlier in the file, or an error in a file you're including directly before including this one? The preprocessor could be doing all sorts of odd things; it's hard to tell what's going on without a lot more context.

If you move the include that's including this header file further up the list of includes, does that change the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably building the second project (or at least the source file) as straight C.  Make sure the file has a .cpp extension or that you are forcing a C++ compile (you can use the `/TP` compile option to do that).

*Edit* You can specify it for a single file:   Right click on the file in the solution explorer and select Properties.  Click on the Advanced option under `C/C++`.  Choose "Compile as C++ Code (/TP)" (second option in the page in my version of Visual Studio).

Comment: Forcing the whole project to compile as C++ causes many problems in code that isn't mine, and would take a long time to track down and fix. Can I force just the one source file to compile as C++?

Comment: @Colin:  Yes, you can specify that option for a single file.  I will add it to the answer.  If you do that, you may have link problems due to name mangling/decoration.  If so you may need to add some `extern "C"` to appropriate headers.

Comment: Hmm. That didn't change things, but it seems like it's ignoring the option. If I exclude the header file from the project, it doesn't seem to be make a difference.

Comment: @Colin: You're saying you removed the header file and you still get the error on that line of the header file?  That seems a bit odd.  You might try to do a rebuild all.  Or close the file and delete the .pch (pre-compiled header) file.

Comment: Colin, you cannot control how the *header* gets compiled. You can only control that for the files that *include* that header. Since the header is evidently C++, you must make sure that no C source files include that header, not even indirectly. And merely removing it from the project won't change anything; if you want to test compilation without that file, you need to make sure that nothing mentions that file in any `#include` statement. Membership in "the project" is irrelevant.

Comment: @Rob: Thanks. That answers some things I was confused about, as the header file was throwing some complaints about an extern "C" line. I threw in a check for cplusplus and that fixed that.