# File Compiles Fine in One Project But Not in Another

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have a large class ClassA that I defined in a Code::Blocks Project ProjectA. ProjectA compiles fine, but when I try to use ClassA in a different project ProjectB, I start getting errors like

```
C:\ProjectA\ClassA.cpp|17|error: boost/foreach.hpp: No such file or directory|
C:\ProjectA\ClassA.cpp|649|error: 'strlen' was not declared in this scope|
```

also one of these for every function in cstring

```
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.1\include\c++\cstring|76|error: '::memchr' has not been declared|
```

I added both ClassA.h and ClassA.cpp to ProjectB and added the folder for ProjectA to the directories searched in ProjectB.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133286/header-file-throwing-errors-in-one-project-but-not-in-another) question addressing a similar error, but I don't use C, so it would be weird for my projects to suddenly start trying to compile in C. However, I don't want to completely dismiss the possibility, so I would also like to know how to check whether a project is compiling in C or C++ in Code::Blocks.

Using files from multiple projects has been working for me up until today, so I'm at a total loss for what could be wrong. Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: You likely have to add Boost to search/link paths in second project.

Comment: How would I deal with the cstring problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `ProjectB` has different include paths, ensure that it has the equivalent to `ProjectA`.  Usually you would setup boost in an external directory.

Comment: ProjectB has all the include paths ProjectA has. How would a difference in include paths make cstring stop working?

Comment: @Eva that was in reference to the foreach include.  I am not sure about memchr.